# When resizing viewport display: table; with fixed width cell leaves 1px space

Tags: html, css, webkit

We have this problem with display: table; in our responsive project(s). Our table is in a wrapper  and displays 100% width. One of the cells is a fixed px width.

When resizing the browser the cells leave a 1px space on the right each 3px te viewport is resized. Is there a solution or workaround for this, we can't seem to find it...

Here's an example made in Codepen, check this in Chrome or Safari and resize your browser window horizontally:
http://codepen.io/jstnrs/pen/RNqOWP

```
.table {
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;  
}

.table-cell {
    display: table-cell;
}

.table-cell-01 {width: 25%;}
.table-cell-02 {width: 25%;}
.table-cell-03 {width: 100px;}
```

Comment: My colleague pointed out it's also applicable when the table contains 2 cells where only one cell has a (fixed) width, see: http://codepen.io/jstnrs/pen/jEQRBZ

Comment: even 1 cell without a width for that matter: http://codepen.io/jstnrs/pen/PwxgJp

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've found a bug in the WebKit rendering engine. The .wrapper class does not appear to be scaling at the same rate as the .table (you can move the background-color up to the .table and get the same effect). Check [here](https://bugs.webkit.org/query.cgi?format=specific&product=WebKit) to see if this bug has been filed before (I didn't find it on a quick search) and, if it hasn't, file one. Congrats!